# Where am I? -Decoding Puzzle

Tags: computer-puzzle

This is a very short and simple decoding computer-puzzle.

---

> Where am I?
>
> I am in a known location called 370031.

Where is this mysterious person?

Clue:

> Most, or half of the people looking at this post, are in 370031!

Comment: IEOOLE? Are you sure it shouldn't be 370013?

Comment: I am 99.9% sure of this number 370013

Comment: You're 99.9% sure of 370013, or of 370031 (which is what you put in the OP)?

Comment: I mean the number 370031. I double checked and still got 370031.

Comment: Can't shake the feeling that this is IP related

Comment: Maybe it's your phone number!

Comment: That doesn't fit the clue of half the people looking at the post being there. Makes me think the answer is home and that we have to do some calculation on 127.0.0.1

Comment: @AndrewSmith You got the answer!

Comment: I'll leave someone else do the equation that makes it equal 370031, that seems the puzzle to me.

Comment: @AndrewSmith Notice it is a computer puzzle. Now, what is an alternative to using standard decimal notation?

Comment: Ah it was short and simple, now I get that :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are at:

> Home = 127.0.0.1 = 127001 = 370031 in octal

Comment: good job. I thought of that but not to convert it in octal. +1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

> you should turn 370031 upside down

to get

> IEOOLE.

I suspect the number should actually be 370013, so that the answer is

> BOOLE,

which sounds more like a place or at least [a person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole)!

Comment: This is a COMPUTER-PUZZLE. Take that into consideration.